# iOS app rejected because of AliPay and Wechat pay

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

This is the response of Apple, anyone here published an IOS app with either AliPay or Wechat pay.

I need help in regards with this.

Thank you.

---

> ￼Specifically, we found that your app includes AliPay (支付寶) and Taobao H5 Payments￼, which provides access to external payment mechanisms and enables the purchase of content, services, or functionality by means other than the in-app purchase API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use other third party payment methods for the purchase of digital goods/content with your app which is going to be consuming with in the app.

So for that apple recommends the use of in-app purchase.

**When can I use third party payment methods?**

- When you are selling physical goods or provide services for the payment you receive.

**When cot user in-app purchase?**

- When you are providing user digital goods like unlocking a game level, buying coins, etc. the you must use in-app purchase.

> For more info. regarding this you can check the Apple's official document **[here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)**

Comment: Yes probably would disable those payments for IOS. China has lot of ways to pay things.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem when I had integrated BrainTree with my application. And then me and my team went ahead with further communication for the same as one of my app had same configuration even though it was acceptable by AppStore.

> So If any of the features or levels in game is opened after paying to
>   the developers then that payment has to be done using In App Purchase.
>   And even in that around 30 to 40% of the amount developers has to pay
>   to the Apple.
>
> And If payment is done like buying pizza or any other shopping in
>   which user does not need to pay anything to open any of the content
>   within app in that case developers can use any payment gateway.

Comment: Thank you! Yes the problem is in China they have other payment methods though.

Comment: Niki! I have blocked access to Alipay and Wechat pay. Do I need to uninstall everything ? because we Use WeChat for Login, and in our android app we need the package for it to work. Is there a way to be approved.

Comment: I don't think so, just removing in-app purchases would do. No need to remove packages or anything if alipay or wechat is not being used anymore from frontend side.

Comment: Thanks! will try it out. Currently just using Platform.OS to remove the front end side since we use it for android.